# Creating an app using the webmap app qgis plugin

Tags: qgis, boundless-suite

I recently attempted to make an app using opensource software.

I tried re-creating an app following the http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/qgis/webappbuilder/tutorials/schools/index.html tutorial.

However after saving it,instead of getting a "do you want to open it in a web browser" option i get "application files have been correctly generated. Use boundlessWebSDK for building the final web app from them."

i have opengeosuites installed on the computer but the boundless isn't showing anywhere in qgis.

How do i get the app to run?

Comment: I've followed that tutorial to no avail myself.  Here's a link to the sdk instructions.  Hopefully it'll work for you: http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/webapps/index.html

Comment: This is the old SDK, web app builder works with the new React based SDK, which is not yet public. Only customers currently have access to it.

Comment: @bartvde Please post your comment as an answer so this thread can be marked as answered

Answer (score 1):

Web App Builder works with the new React based SDK, not the old SDK that is part of OpenGeo Suite right now. Only customers currently have access to it.